# How do I add create-react-kotlin-app as a module to kotlin-multiplatform project?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin-multiplatform project works only with gradle modules but create-react-kotlin-app does not have one?
Could someone assist me with some guidance on how to make them work together, please.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the, rather nifty looking ;-) , [Gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin)?

You can create NPM and Yarn task wrappers, and NPM is *not* required to be installed, Gradle and dependency management takes care of that:

*[Node plugin documentation](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md)
*[Execute NPM Tasks](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md#executing-yarn-tasks)

So, just `gradle --init` in the ReactJS project's root folder, then add the plugin and NPM tasks to your new `build.gradle` file.